# Auto create a folder named by a cell reference in a network location

Tags: excel, vba, directory

Im trying to create a folder in a network location which is already created and then name the new folder a value of 2 cell references combined on a specific sheet.

```
Dim strFilename, strDirname, strPathname, strDefpath As String
'On Error Resume Next
strDirname = ContractorChecklistSheet.Range("B6" & "B7").Value

strFilename = ContractorChecklistSheet.Range("B6" & "B7").Value
strDefpath = "T:\Projects\"

MkDir strDefpath & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & strDirname & "" & strFilename

If IsEmpty(filename) Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

but i cant get it to work, the code halts on strDirname, can someone please help.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named `ContractorChecklistSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a worksheet with a `CodeName` of *ContractorChecklistSheet* then this updated Range will work

```
strDirname = ContractorChecklistSheet.Range("B6").Value & ContractorChecklistSheet.Range("B7").Value
```

Else if your Excel tab is named *ContractorChecklistSheet*, then try

```
strDirname = Sheets("ContractorChecklistSheet").Range("B6").Value & Sheets("ContractorChecklistSheet").Value
```

Note that you should use error checking on `MkDir` to ensure the folder name is valid